# How to order the items of a list and remove duplicates based on a property?

Tags: c#, linq

I've this class:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public int Contributions { get; set; }
}
```

My `List<User>` can contain multiple items with same `Id` but different `Contributions` value.

I want to have distinct values based on `Id`, but with the highest `Contributions` value for that `Id`. How can I do that? thanks.

I tried this but it's only a part of what I want:

```
list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Contributions);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list.GroupBy(u => u.Id) // Distinct
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(u => u.Contributions).First()); // Highest contributions
```